# insert fails with Durable Writes on Node down

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have 2 node cluster with replication={'class' : 'NetworktopologyStrategy','DC':'1'} AND durable_writes=true;

, my insert fails when one of the node is down.

The Consistency level is one.

Comment: Do you invoke the insert from the cqlsh? Paste the trace from the insert.

Comment: select * from stocks where id=1; Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\apache-cassandra-2.1.8-bin\apache-cassandra-2.1.8\bin\\cqlsh", line 1078, in perform_simple_statement
    rows = self.session.execute(statement, trace=self.tracing_enabled)
  File "C:\apache-cassandra-2.1.8-bin\apache-cassandra-2.1.8\bin\..\lib\cassandra-driver-internal-only-2.6.0c2.post.zip\cassandra-driver-2.6.0c2.post\cassandra\cluster.py", line 1594, in execute
    result = future.result(timeout)

Comment: File "C:\apache-cassandra-2.1.8-bin\apache-cassandra-2.1.8\bin\..\lib\cassandra-driver-internal-only-2.6.0c2.post.zip\cassandra-driver-2.6.0c2.post\cassandra\cluster.py", line 3296, in result     raise self._final_exception Unavailable: code=1000 [Unavailable exception] message="Cannot achieve consistency level ONE" info={'required_replicas': 1, 'alive_replicas': 0, 'consistency': 'ONE'}

Answer (score 2):

For all inserts to be successful with one node down, you'd need to use a replication factor of 2.  When you only use a replication factor of 1, the insert may hash to the down node, and so it cannot complete the write.

If you have a replication factor of 2 and do a write with consistency of ONE, then it can write to the node that is still up.

Or if you turn on hinted handoffs and write with a consistency level of ANY, then you could use a replication factor of 1 and the insert would still succeed, but the write would be delayed until the down node came back up.

Comment: Thanks Jim, the keyspace tables are about 65 GB  (10 tables) , changing the RF will require Nodetool repair which will eventually run the repair for each range , is there a way to figure out how much time repair might take.

Comment: If you run "nodetool compactionstats", I think it will show you how many tasks are pending for the repair.  You might be able to estimate the remaining time by monitoring that.